# Getting access to Messages API and Invitation API on Linkedin. #Linkedin

Tags: linkedin-api

Does anyone know how I can get access to writing direct messages using the LinkedIn API? I found a specific endpoint for message tasks at this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/communications/messages. However, it states: "Usage of this API is restricted to approved partners, subject to limitations via API agreement," with no further redirection. I searched the LinkedIn docs, but couldn't find the Communication API which contains the Messages API. Also, in my account dashboard in the user section (shown on image), I cannot find this endpoint. I would be greatly thankful for any help. Additionally, if someone knows exactly where to apply, I would also be grateful. #Linkedin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/go5Ue.png)

I was researching docs. I wrote to Linkedin support, but probably to wrong one, because I haven't got any valuable answer.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing LinkedIn's API for direct messaging is indeed restricted and requires approval as a partner. You should apply directly through LinkedIn's partnership program for access to their Communication API.

Some documents are only available to partners, so try applying directly on their site.

Comment: But where exactly should I write, as I previously said, I wrote to support but I haven't got an answer for my question...